# How can I provide API credentials to Scrapy Cloud without publicly providing the credentials?

Tags: python, scrapy

The one place that I am very lost is in determining how to properly supply API credentials to Scrapy Cloud and Scrapinghub in order to send the parsed items to Google Cloud. I currently am storing my scripts on Github and auto-updating it to Scrapy Cloud. This is in order to make for easier updating to my projects, and also to allow others to see my project progressions.

The issue then arises of how to properly provide the API credentials in order to verify Scrapy data for Google. I can't publicly display the credentials (VERY bad idea I learned). And I don't believe I can both manually upload a JSON file to Scrapy Cloud and store my project in Github. I could only store my projects on Scrapy, but that limits collaboration on the project.

Is there a potential workaround for this? Has anyone been able to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

After reading some obscure Google documentation, I was able to resolve the issue with the initial help below. The process looks like this:

1. Create a set of service account credentials in Google Cloud UI
2. Go into Scrapinghub UI and create a setting in the spider for each
   item in the credentials.
3. Use the "settings.get" function provided by Scrapy to pull those
   credentials in from your Scrapinghub UI.
4. Build a Credentials object from the OAuth2 module.
5. Use the Credentials object as the credentials for the Pub/Sub PublisherClient.

A Github link to how I resolved the issue is here:

https://github.com/cmattheson6/bill_votes/blob/master/senate_votes/pipelines.py

Comment: Scrapy Cloud also offers ways to setup settings. Then you can change the spider to read those credentials from settings without hardcoding them into the code.

Comment: @eLRuLL thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I was able to build a solution off of that. I posted my solution above.

Comment: thanks, your example on your dev branch suited me very well!

Answer (score 0):

What about using Arguments for your spider?

```
def __init__(self, api_credentials=None):
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this; I had to add some more custom scripts to make it work, but it is functional now. I posted my solution above.